# Add a class to an element with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to add a class on my header when the user scrolls. I places this code in an external file **main.js**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
        $('header').addClass("sticky");
    } else {
        $('header').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
```

But there is an error

> Can't find the variable $

Do you have any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery? I suspect not

Comment: If you plan to use jQuery, I suggest to follow the tutorial: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reference the jquery file before you call your main.js
First add a reference to jquery:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

and then reference your main.js

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the mistake. I loaded jquery after the main.js

Answer (score 0):

Can't find the variable `$`means before loading `jquery.min.js` your function getting called somehow .. or you `missed to add jquery.js`

Comment: [`<header>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header) is a valid element.